# After connecting the application with Firebase in Flutter, an empty screen appears , I just connected and did not return data

Tags: flutter

```yaml
name: flutter_application_1
description: "A new Flutter project."`your text`
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.25.4
  firebase_storage: ^11.6.6
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.4
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.5
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.16
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: try restarting the app

Comment: please share you full code